# finding if df column starts with a value and strip or set to none according to the value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas and was wondering if we could write a one line to check and transform the column using lambda .

The pandas column contains values straing with PL and TM .

The idea is to create function transformer to strip PL from a column if ‘PL123’ else set to missing if ‘TM123’

Thanks in advance for help!!!!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to either replace text in the column, or set the value of another column based on the text.  For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'values': ['PL123', 'PL234', 'TM123', 'TM234']})

df.loc[df['values'] == 'PL123', 'values'] = '123'
df.loc[df['values'] == 'TM123', 'values'] = 'missing'

df['new_col'] = ''
df.loc[df['values'].str.startswith('PL'), 'new_col'] = df['values']
df['new_col'] = df['new_col'].str.replace('PL', '')

print(df)
#     values new_col
# 0      123        
# 1    PL234     234
# 2  missing        
# 3    TM234
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sort = lambda x: x[2:] if 'PL' in x else None
record1 = 'PL123'
record2 = 'TM123'
print(sort(record1)) #Test 1: '123'
print(sort(record2)) #Test 2: None

df = pd.DataFrame({'values': ['PL123', 'PL234', 'TM123', 'TM234']})
data = list(df['values']) # Converts records under 'values' column into 
                          # a list so contents can be post processed by 
                          # lambda function

for ele in data:
    print(sort(ele)) #Test 3: '123', '123', None, None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df["your_col"].apply(lambda x: "123" if x=="PL123" else (None if x=="TM123" else x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

if anything, that `startswith`:

```
df['column_name'].map(lambda x: '123' if x.startswith('PL') else "missing")
```

Another, if you are looking for `PL` anywhere in the column and want to transform that to `123` and anything else to `missing` then you can try `str.contains`

```
df['values'].apply(lambda x: '123' if 'PL' in x else "missing")
```